# Deploying a Laravel 10 / Breeze / InertiaJS / Vue project to a subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am trying to deploy a project to a subdirectory on my server to http://localhost/my-project by doing the following. (I have done this successfully before with a similar project but without Breeze.)

1.) copy all the files except public to /var/www/my-project_code

2.) copy contents of public/ to /var/www/html/my-project

3.) change the links in /var/www/html/my-project/index.php to link to new location of the php files

4.) in resources/views/app.blade.php, replace @routes and @vite directives with <script type="module" tags linking to all the .js files in build/assets, and also a  for the .css file

5.) add the following to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/my-project>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

6.) fix the bug(?) in inertiaJS that doubles up the root url by editing this file:

vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Response.php
..and replacing this line:

```
'url' => $request->getBaseUrl().$request->getRequestUri(),
```

..with

```
'url' => $request->getRequestUri(),
```

But it is not working and I am getting the error:

ReferenceError: Ziggy is not defined

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

If it is useful to anyone, I am putting all of the above in a command line php script here:

https://github.com/alexwindsor/laravel-deploy

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Ziggy for your Laravel routes. Read the instructions here: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy